# Validity of approach to nonlinear, driven, damped oscillation amplitudes in L&L

Tags: classical-mechanics, resonance, non-linear-systems

In §29 of L&L mechanics, the authors discuss an approach to estimate the resonance amplitude of the equation
$\ddot{x}+2\lambda\dot{x}+\omega_0^2x = \frac{f}{m}\cos(\gamma t)-\alpha x^2-\beta x^3$ 
In particular, they use the formula for the amplitude b of the driven oscillation derived from the problem without nonlinearities,
$b^2 = \frac{f^2}{(\epsilon^2+\lambda^2)4m^2\omega_0^2}$,
where $\epsilon = \gamma-\omega_0$ is the distance of the driving frequency from the natural frequency.
They combine this with the fact that the frequency of the same system *without driving or damping* changes when we successively solve the problem order for order, where the first correction takes place in the second order of b.
I accept the fact that - regardless of the specific problem - the first correction to $\omega$ is of second order.

However, I don't see how or why this approach, i.e. replacing $\epsilon$ with $\epsilon - \kappa b^2$ is consistent. After all, the formula for $b(\epsilon)$ might very well change fundamentally when the amplitude is higher and nonlinearities become relevant. One might argue that we only increase the amplitude by a little bit, but the resulting equation from the approach is of order up to $b^6$, which is already a high enough order for us to expect changes to the formula. Can anybody explain why this method is consistent nonetheless?

Edit: I have a theory as to what the logic might be here, but I'm still not 100% sure it is consistent:
If we take the 0th order (the unpertubed problem) which has the normal solution and is of order b, the frequency of the non-decaying part (the homogenous solution) still has the pertubed frequency in it. So the approximation must be that we take the 0th order in $x(t)$ but combine it with the 2nd order of $\omega$, which is like in QM perturbation theory where we calculate the 1st order energy shift but keep the 0th order wave function. Is this what lies behing all of this?

Comment: You mean that the natural frequency should not change proportional to just $b^2$, but include all orders, so $\epsilon - \kappa b^2$ should become $\epsilon - \kappa b^2 - \lambda b^4 - \mu b^6 \ \dots$. Am I reading the question correctly in that way?

Comment: I was rather wondering why it is permitted to use only the zeroth term in the expansion $x(t) = x^{(0)} + x^{(1)} + ...$ to find a formula for $b(\epsilon)$ and afterwards plug in the *second* order expansion of $\omega = \omega^{(0)} + \omega^{(1)} + \omega^{(2)}+...$. Wouldnt consistency dictate that it is necessary to find the formula for $b(\epsilon)$ using the second order in $x$ and then plug in the second order in $\omega$?